# Hardware requirments to implement 4K textures in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I've been working on Environment Designing in unreal engine 3 for a long time, and i want to shift to unreal engine 4 now.

My aim is to create an environment, in which every texture will be 4K and uncompressed, plus the dynamic reflections and all the photo realism effects with 4K in-game Resolution and should run on about 120 frames/sec.
I just want to test the capabilities of the engine, so, **I want to know the specifications of a rig that will be needed to process and develop all this with ease**.

All help will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no game with 4K texture works 120fps , and as far as I know, unreal engine doesnt support SLI by default .

However, if you have GTX 1080 with Decent i7 cpu , you can hit around 80-45fps depends on how heavy is your scene .

you can develop on GTX 1070 , and it run pretty ok , however, I dont know how far u will do , I work with GTX 1070 , and its too smooth for everything . you need more GPU memory , so never sacrifice with GPU for other things costs

Comment: I'm basically trying to recreate the unreal 4 forest demo but i'm trying to go for better more detailed foliage...just to see how far it can go.